# How is RFC 5545 different from RFC 2445

Tags: calendar, standards, icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445

In native Android calendar app, RFC 2445 protocol is used to create `.ics` files. I found in some blogs that RFC 2445 is replaced with RFC 5545. Can anyone please tell me what are the extra features in RFC 5545 and how it is different from RFC 2445?

Answer (score 24):

Why don't you compare [RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445) with [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)?

In particular, RFC 5545's cover page states that it obsoletes RFC 2445, and has an appendix dedicated to the [differences from RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#appendix-A):

> ```
> Appendix A.  Differences from RFC 2445
>   A.1.  New Restrictions
>   A.2.  Restrictions Removed
>   A.3.  Deprecated Features
> ```

(The changes cited are all minor (or, at least, succinct) as far as I can see)

Answer (score 6):

The main one, (for me), really, is that there is no longer a repeating rule for exception dates in vevents. You have to list them individually.

The other main one is that the author, 'The Bernard', got a second chance at the whole thing and improved on the TOC and other organizational aspects of the standard.

Additionally, there are some better clarifications and some subtle changes as well.

There are a total of 11 listed in the links in the other answer above.

MAKE SURE to look at the errata pages available on the rfc-editor.org site. Make sure to look at each errata's STATUS before using it.

I recently found an issue, wrote it up (backwards for the fix, however), the correct fix was written up by 'The Bernard', and it will be accepted I'm sure. There are about 10 errata, as I remember.